# Return paginated output recursively with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, pagination, fetch-api

#### Summary

I'd like to collate paginated output into an array using JavaScript's Fetch API recursively. Having started out with promises, I thought an async/await function would be more suitable.

#### Attempt

Here's my approach:

```js
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function fetchRequest(url) {
  try {
    // Fetch request and parse as JSON
    const response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json();

    // Extract the url of the response's "next" relational Link header
    let next_page = /<([^>]+)>; rel="next"/g.exec(response.headers.get("link"))[1];

    // If another page exists, merge it into the array
    // Else return the complete array of paginated output
    if (next_page) {
      data = data.concat(fetchRequest(next_page));
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    }

  } catch (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
}

// Live demo endpoint to experiment with
fetchRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.cypress.io/posts?_page=9");
```

For this demo, it should result in 2 requests which yield a single array of 20 objects. Although the data is returned, I can't fathom how to collate it together into an array. Any guidance would be really appreciated. Thanks for your time.

#### Solution #1

Thanks to @ankit-gupta:

```js
async function fetchRequest(url) {
  try {
    // Fetch request and parse as JSON
    const response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json();

    // Extract the url of the response's "next" relational Link header
    let next_page;
    if (/<([^>]+)>; rel="next"/g.test(response.headers.get("link"))) {
      next_page = /<([^>]+)>; rel="next"/g.exec(response.headers.get("link"))[1];
    }

    // If another page exists, merge its output into the array recursively
    if (next_page) {
      data = data.concat(await fetchRequest(next_page));
    }
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
}

fetchRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.cypress.io/posts?_page=9").then(data =>
  console.log(data)
);
```

For each page, subsequent calls are made recursively and concatenated together into one array. Would it be possible to chain these calls in parallel, using [Promises.all](https://dev.to/jamesliudotcc/how-to-use-async-await-with-map-and-promise-all-1gb5), similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60590875/8377918)?

On a side note, any ideas why StackOverflow Snippets fails on the second Fetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap `next_page` in a condition, otherwise it will lead to type error on the last call (Since `/<([^>]+)>; rel="next"/g.exec(response.headers.get("link"))` will be null)

Before concating data, you need the promise to get resolved.

Making some minor changes to your code can result in the correct output:

```
global.fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function fetchRequest(url) {
  try {
    // Fetch request and parse as JSON
    const response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json();

    // Extract the url of the response's "next" relational Link header
    let next_page;
    if(/<([^>]+)>; rel="next"/g.exec(response.headers.get("link")))
        next_page = /<([^>]+)>; rel="next"/g.exec(response.headers.get("link"))[1];

    // If another page exists, merge it into the array
    // Else return the complete array of paginated output
    if (next_page) {
      let temp_data = await fetchRequest(next_page); 
      data = data.concat(temp_data);
    }

    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
}

// Live, demo endpoint to experiment
fetchRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.cypress.io/posts?_page=9").then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response, I really appreciate it!    

Instead of repeating the `RegExp.exec` in the conditions and logic, would it be more efficient to use a `RegExp.test` in the condition instead?    

Is it advisable to bypass `temp_data` by moving the `fetchRequest()` call directly into `data.concat()`?    

What do you think of this script's structure; can it be improved? Would it be possible to chain calls in parallel [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60590700/8377918)?

Comment: For chaining calls in parallel, you need to remove dependency of getting the next link from response's header. Do you need to depend on every response's `next` relational link? What I mean to say is if you know the starting point is `https://jsonplaceholder.cypress.io/posts?_page=8` and ending point is `https://jsonplaceholder.cypress.io/posts?_page=10`, you can create the intermediate links yourself, right?

Comment: Yes you can definitely move `fetchRequest()` call directly into `data.concat()`. I wrote it that way just to give a clear understanding of what's going on.